# Использование async await в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Кто-то может сказать как такую конструкцию заставить работать?
На данный момент возвращает UnityExtension

> UnityException: get_canAccess can only be called from the main thread.
> Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene.
> Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.

```
    private async void Awake()
    {
        Mesh protoMesh = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
        SelfMesh = await InitMeshAsync(protoMesh);
    }

    protected async Task<CustomMesh> InitMeshAsync(Mesh protoMesh)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => new CustomMesh(protoMesh.vertices, protoMesh.triangles));
    }
```

Comment: Ну или посоветуйте как просто вынести часть кода не MonoBehaviour в отдельный поток. Хочется чего-то более высокоуровневого чем Threading.

Comment: Не путайте асинхронность и многопоточность. А вопрос - это пока проблема XY.

Answer (score 0):

В Unity многие вещи можно делать только в главном треде. Одна из таких вещей это создание Mesh и его наследников (подозреваю, что CustomMesh наследует Mesh). А Task.Run выполняет задачу в другом треде. Поэтому надо писать так:

```
private void Awake()
{
    Mesh protoMesh = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    SelfMesh = new CustomMesh(protoMesh.vertices,protoMesh.triangles);
}
```

P.S. бывают случаи при создании мешей, когда расчет позиций вертексов и треугольников занимает много времени и хочется вынести это в отдельный тред (при процедурной генерации например). И это можно делать при помощи Task, но опять же вызывать `new Mesh()` можно только в основном треде.

Answer (score -1):

Для этого необходимо передать `TaskScheduler`, созданный на основе главного потока и использовать `Task.Factory.StartNew()` для получения элементов `Mesh` полагая, что `new CustomMesh()` не использует вызовы элементов Unity:

```cs
private async void Awake()
{
    Mesh protoMesh = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    var mainTaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    SelfMesh = await Task.Run(() => InitMeshAsync(protoMesh, mainTaskScheduler));
}

protected async Task<CustomMesh> InitMeshAsync(Mesh protoMesh, TaskScheduler scheduler)
{
    Vector3[] vertices = null;
    int[] triangles = null;
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
         vertices = protoMesh.vertices;
         triangles = protoMesh.triangles;
    }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, scheduler);
    return new CustomMesh(vertices, triangles);
}
```

Можно упростить код и получить переменные `vertices` и `triangles` сразу в `Awake()`, а потом передать в `InitMeshAsync()`, чтобы не создавать лишний `await`, если это допустимо.

Если же `new CustomMesh()` использует вызовы элементов Unity, то использование асинхронности в данном случае не имеет смысла, поскольку всё придётся выполнять в главном потоке.

В случае доступа не из главного потока все вызовы к элементам Unity необходимо делать через такие функции (например, `AddComponent<T>()`, `new Mesh()`). В простых случаях следующего набора функций должно хватить:

```cs
public static Task RunAsyncWithScheduler(Action action, TaskScheduler scheduler) => 
    Task.Factory.StartNew(action, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, scheduler);

public static Task<T> RunAsyncWithScheduler<T>(Func<T> func, TaskScheduler scheduler) =>
    Task.Factory.StartNew(func, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, scheduler);
```

Неочевидным, как по мне, элементами Unity являются `UnityEngine.Random` и свойства (например, `tranform`). Так же я нашёл некоторые исключения из правил: `new Gradient()`, `Mathf`.